# Javac: file not found Error

Tags: java, command

I do not know very much about coding but I am beginning to edit the source code for a Runescape Private Server. My only problem right now is that I can't use the server compiler. I get the error:

> "javac: file not found: src\server\event*.java 
>   Usage: javac  "

This is what I have for the code. All I have edited from the original that I downloaded is my jdk directory.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac.exe" -classpath deps/log4j-1.2.15.jar;deps/jython.jar;deps/xstream.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/poi.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar  -d bin src\server\event\*.java src\server\model\items\*.java src\server\model\minigames\*.java src\server\model\npcs\*.java src\server\model\objects\*.java src\server\model\players\*.java src\server\model\players\skills\*.java src\server\model\players\packets\*.java src\server\model\shops\*.java src\server\net\*.java src\server\task\*.java src\server\util\*.java src\server\world\*.java src\server\util\log\*.java src\server\*.java src\server\world\map\*.java
pause
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The java compiler excutable is called `javac.exe`. `java.exe` is the JVM used to *run* the program.

Comment: Also, you need the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (Java Development Kit) to compile Java source code, the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) does not include the Java compiler (`javac`).

Comment: Okay, editing the OP. Now I have a different error.

Comment: Well, a "file not found" error means exactly what the error message says...

Comment: perhaps you should split that monster of a command line to several calls of javac ...

Comment: Azure that was just my mistake on pasting. Okay, I get it now, after the -d it's looking in these folders for .java files? Right now none of these folders exist. Does that mean I need to do the src\.......\*.java for every folder that contains a java file? I tried it for two folders but got 100 errors.

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is what the "-d bin [....]" is doing here. What needs to go in place of the [....] ? I have a lot of folders with a lot of java files in them.

Comment: It's not `-d bin [...]`.  It's `-d bin` (put the output in "bin") and `[...]` (list of source files to compile).  To answer your earlier comment, yes, all the source files need to go there.  That's why people don't normally compile large projects loose on the command-line, but instead use an IDE or makefile or some sort.

Comment: Thanks Azure. This makes sense now. I tried this with eclipse but I'm too much of a noob to figure out how to compile it. I just rewrote the whole compile code with the directories to every .java file. However, now I am getting 100 errors (though the errors just seem to be ";" or ">" expected... Yes I probably should figure out eclipse then to fix these all at once.